# SQL permissions for roles

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit confused about permissions in SQL

I have created a medical database.

As a script I'm creating a doctor role and I want to say they can perform updates on tables 1,2 and 3.

The database though actually contains 5 tables.

does it mean that they wont be able to update 4 and 5 ?

or will i have to explicitly say deny update on tables 4 and 5 for the doctor role ?

Comment: can you post the script you are using to create the doctor role? will help us determine how the permissions will be set.

Comment: By default, users have no rights. If you GRANT rights to a particular user on a particular table that user won't have rights to any other.

Comment: deny rights supersede grants.  But you do have to be careful with SQL, as giving someone the right to execute a stored procedure will allow that user to do everything contained in the stored procedure.  E.g., a proc that updates all tables would still update all tables if the user is allowed to run that proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the role was made dbo, db_owner or db_datawriter, it won't have permission to edit any data.  If you want to grant full edit permissions to a single table, do this:

```
GRANT ALL ON table1 TO doctor
```

Users in that role will have no permissions whatsoever to other tables (not even read).

Answer (score 1):

SQL-Server follows the principle of "Least Privilege" -- you must (explicitly) grant permissions.

'does it mean that they wont be able to update 4 and 5 ?'

If your users in the doctor role are *only* in the doctor role, then yes.

However, if those users are **also in other roles** (namely, other roles that do have access to 4 & 5), then no.

More Information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
USE DataBaseName;
GO
--------- CREATE ROLE ---------
CREATE ROLE Doctors ;
GO

---- Assign Role To users -------

CREATE USER [Username] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Username]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'Doctors', N'Username'

----- GRANT Permission to Users Assinged with this Role-----
GRANT ALL ON Table1, Table2, Table3 TO Doctors;
GO
```